# Ember causes a routing issue only when I use a Mixin. How do I resolve this?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

In my Ember CLI application, I have a route called *insights*. The route extends the *check-user* mixin.

**/routes/insights.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import CheckUser from 'client-web/mixins/check-user';

export default Ember.Route.extend(CheckUser, {
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    var _this = this;

    if (this.get('userAuthenticated') === true) {
        // Do some stuff here
    } else {
        _this.transitionToRoute('sign-in');
    }
},

getToday: function() {
    var today   = new Date(),
        dd      = today.getDate(),
        mm      = today.getMonth() + 1,
        yyyy    = today.getFullYear();

    if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;
    if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;

    today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

    return today;
},

getTomorrow: function() {
    var toDate  = new Date(this.getToday());
    toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate() + 1);

    var day         = toDate.getDate(),
        month       = toDate.getMonth() + 1,
        year        = toDate.getFullYear();

    if (day < 10) day = '0' + day;
    if (month < 10) month = '0' + month;

    var tomorrow = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;

    return tomorrow;
}
});
```

When I transition to the route from another route using this.transitionTo('insights') or manually refresh the page to myapplication.com/insights, everything works fine and this route renders the template I have specified. However, I have some links in my template that use the {{link-to}} helper to link to the insights route. When a user clicks on one of those links, I get the following error:

```
Error while processing route: insights undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function
at __exports__.default.Ember.Route.extend.setupController (client-web/routes/insights.js:15:14)
at apply (http://localhost:3000/assets/vendor.js:21144:27)
at superWrapper [as setupController] (http://localhost:3000/assets/vendor.js:20721:15)
at EmberObject.extend.setup (http://localhost:3000/assets/vendor.js:51254:18)
at handlerEnteredOrUpdated (http://localhost:3000/assets/vendor.js:54266:36)
at http://localhost:3000/assets/vendor.js:54235:18
at forEach (http://localhost:3000/assets/vendor.js:55303:54)
at setupContexts (http://localhost:3000/assets/vendor.js:54234:9)
at finalizeTransition (http://localhost:3000/assets/vendor.js:54404:9)
at http://localhost:3000/assets/vendor.js:53954:20
```

The line 15 in question is the *getToday* function. Not sure why it's breaking there only when I use the link-to helper. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transitionToRoute` is a controller method. The method on routes is `transitionTo`.

I think your line numbers may be off because of the transpilation. You can see from the stack trace that the error is being thrown inside `setupController`. By the way, if you define your functions like `setupController: function Insights$setupController() ...` you'll get nicer traces.

Minor points: First, I don't know why your're bothering to define `_this`. Second, don't do this kind of check in `setupController`; `beforeModel` would be better. Third, I'm not a big fan of the redundant `=== true`.

**SEE COMMENTS FOR FIX**
Essentially, changing setupController to beforeModel fixed the bug.

Comment: I declare _this to handle some stuff in the if statement where it says '// Do some stuff here'. The _this is required because of jQuery. Changed the transitionTo. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Nagarjun and did that fix the problem?

Comment: Changing setupController to beforeModel seems to have fixed that bug but it has introduced another. Now, my script is rendering the sign-in route because the value of this.get('userAuthenticated') seems to be false. Remember userAuthenticated is a property inside the Mixin check-user. The value of userAuthenticated is set to true while on another page that also uses that mixin. Don't mixin property values carry forward when someone uses the link-to helper?

Comment: Well, the route is instantiated once and at that point the mixin is included into the instance. Any 'transitionTo` (or `{{link-to}}`) will invoke the one instance of the router. The question is when the `userAuthenticated` property is being set by the mixin. You might want to dig down into it and see. It's possible it's not being set by the time 'beforeModel' is being called. By the way, when using mixins like this, you may need to call `_super` here and there, because otherwise the hook by the same name in the mixin will never be called.

Comment: userAuthenticated is set in the init function within the mixin so it looks like it is running before the beforeModel judging by my console.log()s. I did manage to fix the issue though. I changed the logic inside the Mixin to set the userAuthenticated property before the beforeModel and it works now. Thank you!